# Dynamic paper-toolbar background in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm using Polymer 1.0 Starter Kit. I'm trying to change toolbar's background and color when changing routes.

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel main id="headerPanelMain" condenses keep-condensed-header
    header-height="256" condensed-header-height="100">
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
      <span class="space"></span>
      <!-- Toolbar icons -->
      <nt-toolbar-icons></nt-toolbar-icons>
      <!-- Application name -->
      <div class="middle middle-container">
        <div class="app-name">[[route.title]]</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Application sub title -->
      <div class="bottom bottom-container">
        <div class="bottom-title">[[route.subline]]</div>
      </div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <div style="height: 1400px;">
      <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route.name}}">
        <section data-route="home">
          {{route.title}} /
        </section>
        <section data-route="users">
          users {{route.params.type}}
        </section>
      </iron-pages>
    </div>
  </paper-scroll-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

Route is defined in elements/routing.html

```
page('/', function() {
    app.route = {
      name: 'home',
      title: 'noTos+',
      subline: ''
    }
  });
```

In my shared-styles.html my toolbar is defined this way:

```
paper-scroll-header-panel#headerPanelMain {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: var(--paper-grey-200, #eee);

      /* background for toolbar when it is at its full size */
      --paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header: {
        background-image: url(../images/headers/bg4.jpg);
      }
      /* background for toolbar when it is condensed */
      --paper-scroll-header-panel-condensed-header: {
        background-color: var(--paper-light-blue-600);
      }
    }
```

But now I want this color/background-scheme to be changed when the route is changed. 
I've tried adding  data-route$="[[route.name]]" to paper-scroll-header-panel.
Then I've changed shared-styles.html with the [data-route="home"] selector:

```
paper-scroll-header-panel#headerPanelMain[data-route="home"] {
    --paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header: {
        background-image: url(../images/headers/bg3.jpg); //BG CHANGES HERE
      }
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom styles are only applied at creation time. If you have dynamic changes like you do here, you need to call `updateStyles` on you custom element or `Polymer.updateStyles` for a global update. In your case, you would do that when the route changes. You can find more info in the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#dynamism-limitations).

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following.

```
<paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="tall" style$={{computedStyleHandler(color)}}>


computedStyleHandler: function(color){
  return 'background-color:' + color + ';'
}
```